# Formula for taking only certain data from cells

Tags: excel, function

I'm compiling a data chart where each horizontal cell is a separate transaction. I want to make it so the "Profits" column will have a formula that picks data from column E and C for the same horizontal data cell they are on.

I've been searching for this with no luck, probably because I'm not describing it correctly maybe.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understood your question right but you can just use `=C4+E4` assuming your current row is 4. Then move your mouse over the small little box at the bottom right corner and left click and move mouse down.

[image]

The number for the rows will be adjusted accordingly

[image: Image while drag and drop]

Final result:

[image: Solution]

Comment: You are welcome! As a hint: If you want to fix one of the cells having only adjusted the other one, then use a dollar sign, e.g. `=$E$4 + C4`. You can also adjust only the column `=$E4` or the row `=E$4`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you are wanting to do is perform some basic multiplication. This can be achieved using the following formula (only applied to one row for simplicity)

```
=C2*E2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good spot. Completely unnecessary in the case of this example. Answer has been amended.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without going into every single cell and typing =C2*E2 then the next cell =C3*E3 and so on?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the MS Excel autofill option which will apply the function to each row that you select in your worksheet.